# printing digits in assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I've written this code using some instructions I found on the Internet to convert some digits which has been calculated by assembly program and then stored in a register or storage. THen I can not cannot figure out how to print SI which contains converted number. I think I need to find a way to go back in the SI, and save the data first. Has anyone have got any Ideas?

```
;CONVERTING DIGITS 


MOV  AX, HORIZONTAL
MOV  BX, 10         ;DIGITS ARE EXTRACTED DIVIDING BY 10.
MOV  CX, 0          ;COUNTER FOR EXTRACTED DIGITS.

CYCLE1:       
MOV  DX, 0          ;REMAINDER OF DIV WILL BE STORED HERE
DIV  BX             ;DX:AX / 10 = AX:QUOTIENT DX:REMAINDER.
PUSH DX             ;PRESERVE DIGIT EXTRACTED FOR LATER.
INC  CX             ;INCREASE COUNTER FOR EVERY DIGIT EXTRACTED. 

CMP  AX,0           ;TO SEE IF NUMBER IS
JNE  CYCLE1         ;NOT ZERO, LOOP BACK. 

;NOW RETRIEVING PUSHED DIGITS.

MOV  SI, OFFSET HORIZONTAL  
MOV  TMP1, CX
CYCLE2:  
POP  DX        
ADD  DL, 48    ;CONVERT DIGIT TO CHARACTER.
MOV  [SI], DL
INC  SI
LOOP CYCLE2


MOV AH,9            ; print string
MOV DX, OFFSET SI
INT 21h
```

Comment: I don't know how `mov dx, offset si` compiles, when it should read `mov dx, offset HORIZONTAL`. Additionally you may need to terminate the string with '$' before calling the print service -- `mov byte ptr [si], 36`

Comment: It looks like you are using `HORIZONTAL` for both the numeric value (16 bit "word" deducted from `mov ax,[HORIZONTAL]`, and for output string (which may be 6 bytes long in worst case, for values 10000..65535), so did you allocate enough space there, or you don't mind overwriting the following bytes in memory?

Comment: There is another answer for your question, check it out!

Answer (score 2):

Your code is almost perfect, it just needs another variable for the string, copy-paste next code in EMU and run :

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data

HORIZONTAL DW 61503  ;◄■■ TEST NUMBER.
RESULT     DB 6 DUP('$') ;◄■■ VARIABLE FOR THE STRING ☻.
TMP1       DW ?

.code
  mov  ax, @data
  mov  ds, ax

;CONVERTING DIGITS ( ▼ YOUR CODE ▼ ).

MOV  AX, HORIZONTAL
MOV  BX, 10         ;DIGITS ARE EXTRACTED DIVIDING BY 10.
MOV  CX, 0          ;COUNTER FOR EXTRACTED DIGITS.

CYCLE1:       
MOV  DX, 0          ;REMAINDER OF DIV WILL BE STORED HERE
DIV  BX             ;DX:AX / 10 = AX:QUOTIENT DX:REMAINDER.
PUSH DX             ;PRESERVE DIGIT EXTRACTED FOR LATER.
INC  CX             ;INCREASE COUNTER FOR EVERY DIGIT EXTRACTED. 

CMP  AX,0           ;TO SEE IF NUMBER IS
JNE  CYCLE1         ;NOT ZERO, LOOP BACK. 

;NOW RETRIEVING PUSHED DIGITS.

MOV  SI, OFFSET RESULT ;◄■■ VARIABLE FOR THE STRING.
MOV  TMP1, CX
CYCLE2:  
POP  DX        
ADD  DL, 48    ;CONVERT DIGIT TO CHARACTER.
MOV  [SI], DL
INC  SI
LOOP CYCLE2


MOV AH,9            ; print string
MOV DX, OFFSET RESULT ;◄■■ VARIABLE FOR THE STRING.
INT 21h

  mov  ax, 4c00h
  int  21h
```

Answer (score 1):

For DOS service 09h, which prints a string to the standard output, `DS:DX` should contain a pointer to to the $-terminated string. So you have two tasks in order to print the string:

1. Add a $ character to the end of the string to mark its end.
2. Place a pointer to the beginning of the string in the `DX` register.

Your current code is wrong because it doesn't do either of these two things. Remember that, while the `SI` register *does* contain a pointer, after the loops are done, it contains a pointer to the *end* of the string, which is not what you want. You need a pointer to the beginning of the string. Fortunately, `HORIZONTAL` is the offset of the beginning of the string buffer, so you can just use that! (The segment register, `DS`, doesn't need to change.)

So, what your code needs to look like is:

```
; Terminate string
mov  BYTE PTR [si], '$'

; Print string
mov  dx, OFFSET HORIZONTAL
mov  ah, 09h
int  21h
```